# Is it possible to copy&paste image data to the clipboard, like on desktop OSs?

Tags: android, bitmap, clipboard

On desktop OSs, in image-editing apps, you can copy a part of the image and then go to another app and paste it.

Is it also possible and officially supported on Android?

If so, what are the capabilities of such a feature? is there a limit to the number of pixels, for example, that can be copied?

All I've found is that those are the types of data (link [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html)):

> Text - A text string. You put the string directly into the clip object,
>   which you then put onto the clipboard. To paste the string, you get
>   the clip object from the clipboard and copy the string to into your
>   application's storage.
>
> URI -  A Uri object representing any form of URI. This is primarily
>   for copying complex data from a content provider. To copy data, you
>   put a Uri object into a clip object and put the clip object onto the
>   clipboard. To paste the data, you get the clip object, get the Uri
>   object, resolve it to a data source such as a content provider, and
>   copy the data from the source into your application's storage.
>
> Intent -  An Intent. This supports copying application shortcuts. To
>   copy data, you create an Intent, put it into a clip object, and put
>   the clip object onto the clipboard. To paste the data, you get the
>   clip object and then copy the Intent object into your application's
>   memory area.

Comment: why the downvote? please write something before you downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.  There is no direct way to paste image data.  You may be able to do it like this though:

1)Create a clip with a URI.  You'll need to define a URI to that part of the photo
2)Write a content provider which provides an image MIME type.
3)Have the content provider pass along the data you wanted to paste when the URI from part 1 is requested.

It will obviously not work in all apps, as the paster needs to be able to understand and expect the image MIME type for a clip data URI.  Most apps won't would be my guess.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Say, about the URI solution, how woule you know when to delete the file you've created? Or you actually don't create a file?

Comment: There's no real way to say that a clip is no longer used, so you'd have to more or less guess.  Either cleanup on a regular schedule or when the app is launched.  Or just always use the same file to hold the data (not keeping old copies), so you never have more than 1 of them around.

Comment: so you do create a file. but if the file is being used by the other app (to send over the internet), you should know when it's done, so that you could delete it. would putting the file into the cache folder be enough?

Comment: You can't really depend on Android deleting your caches in a timely fashion-  it will only do so when total storage gets low.  The documentation suggests clearing the cache on your own.

Comment: so there is no way to delete such files when the other app finished using it... anyway, thanks.